# iterative subprocesses in python with different runtime

Tags: java, python, runtime, subprocess, cpu

I'm writing a python script than runs for x iterations. In each iteration I start a subprocess to call a java process. The weird thing is, that the cpu runtime of my java process differs massively and at iteration y I get a java failure message that the java heap size is exceeded.

```
p=subprocess.Popen([cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)                                     
    (output,errput)=p.communicate() #waits until the process is terminated          
    return output
```

Comment: Are you reading your pipe in the Java process? I'm guessing no.

Comment: And I hope the `cmd` variable is carefully sanitized (if it is a variable).

Comment: if you pass `shell=True` the first argument should be a string, rather than a list

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - why would that make any difference?

Comment: @GP89 I'm pretty sure that's not his actual usage, but rather a placeholder for the purposes of the question, so he wouldn't have to type in the full command.

Comment: @tdelaney The piped bytes go into a buffer until you read them. If you don't read them and keep sending more, eventually you exhaust the heap.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `communicate` does read from the buffer, though

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - this script doesn't send anything to the java process and consumes everything the java process produces as part of the communicate() call. Anyway, even if pipes were full, it may hang this iteration, but it wouldn't make a difference to the next iteration.

Comment: It seems crazy to me to spawn multiple JVM processes; have you considered using another IPC mechanism?

Comment: Grasping at straws here... but the script only waits for the launched shell to return, not the java program. If the java process detaches (like maybe a gui app), then its still churning away in the background. It could even be running more threads in a single java instance (e.g., running a browser twice just adds another window to the existing browser).

Comment: @tdelaney how can I wait for the java process to terminate? I thought if I get the output on the shell, the java process would be finished too.

Comment: @AlexThornton What do you mean with variable is carefully sanitized? I'm new in python ... So, the cmd variable is the actual command I want to run on the shell. I thought I have to put it into a list.

Comment: @TrK What I'm saying is, if the input is coming from an untrusted source they could execute arbitrary commands on your system; due to the fact that you have included `shell=True` in the arguments.

Comment: @AlexThornton I use the following command 'java -jar path/to/program.jar --infile ifile -- outfile ofile'

Comment: @TrK - it depends on the process. What happens when you run it from the console? Does the prompt come back immediately? One option is to run cmd as a list with shell=False and then poll the pid to see when its done. But generally, you'll have to figure out the rules for this particular program.

Comment: @tdelaney - I did run the java program in a bash script for 10000 times iteratively and it took always the same runtime. So, it's weird, in my python script I do the same.

Comment: @tdelaney - How can I poll the pid?